# Fazendo scrape no Instagram

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu gostaria de sabe se é possível "pegar" os link de todas as fotos de um perfil do instragram sem usar a Api?

Com o codigo abaixo eu consigo pegar apenas as 20 fotos mais recentes.

```
$.getJSON('https://crossorigin.me/https://www.instagram.com/nygiants/media', 
function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Eu desconfio que não dá sem um token de acesso: http://instagram.pixelunion.net/ , uma vez que tenha pode usar o next_url (https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/) para fazer uma paginação. EX: https://techchurian.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/displaying-all-your-instagram-images-ignoring-next-page-and-pagination/